# Cast to Array failed for value "[]" (type Array) at path "pathname" because of "TypeError"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, typeerror

I'm working on a social media project using `next.js`. I want to implement `unfollow` feature in my app.

**I'm getting this error -->**

**CastError: Cast to Array failed for value "[]" (type Array) at path "followers" because of "TypeError"**

In backend, modal for `User` is created as

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const schema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
     followers : {
            type : [mongoose.Schema.objectId],
            ref : "User",
        }
)
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", schema);
```

When user clicks unfollow button, following function will be called.

```
    const unFollowUser = async (userId)=>{
        const result = await instance.post(`/user/unfollow/${userId}`, { followers : getUser()})
        console.log(result)
    }
```

I want to unfollow `userId` and I will pass my id as `{ followers : getUser()}`.

Below is the route I have created for removing the id from follower's array.

```
router.post('/user/unfollow/:id', async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id : req.params.id })
        const followers = user.followers.filter( item => item != req.body.followers)
        user.followers = followers
        user.save()
        res.status(200).send({message : "Success"})
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
})
```

I have created my in such a way that when user clicks `follow` button, user's id will be saved to another user's followers array.

type of `followers` is set as objectId, but in the code `user.followers = followers` I'm trying to set array value to followers. Can anyone help?

Expexted output is to save filtered `_id` to follower's array

Comment: Remember: if you get an error, [show that error in your post](/help/how-to-ask). Your title is not where problem details go, it's only the "subject line" so folks have a rough idea what you're asking about while scrolling through the questions feed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are a typo issue in your code that are causing the error. Let's go through the issues step by step.

In your Mongoose schema definition, you have a small typo. Instead of mongoose.Schema.objectId, it should be mongoose.Schema.ObjectId with a capital 'O' and 'I'.

Change this:

```
type : [mongoose.Schema.objectId],
```

to this:

```
type : [mongoose.Schema.ObjectId],
```

With this changes, your code should be working perfectly fine now. if not then let me know